# what kind of data is transferred on the network in case of RESTful webservice

Tags: web-services, rest

I know about the SOAP -based webservices that SOAP messages, which are XML in turn, are transferred on the network, from client to the server. But what kind of data is transferred in case of RESTful webservice ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type

Comment: Too basic question. Use the wikipedia or google instead.

Answer (score 1):

from Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer

> RESTful systems typically, but not always, communicate over the
>   Hypertext Transfer Protocol with the same HTTP verbs (GET, POST, PUT,
>   DELETE, etc.)

You can try yourself easily with curl or Fiddler. For example GitHub API is nice to experiment with.

Send this with Fiddler:

GET https://api.github.com/users/octocat HTTP/1.1
Host: api.github.com
User-Agent: Fiddler

and you will get this response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: GitHub.com
Date: Fri, 10 Jul 2015 10:23:10 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 1155
Status: 200 OK
X-RateLimit-Limit: 60
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 58
X-RateLimit-Reset: 1436527371
Cache-Control: public, max-age=60, s-maxage=60
Last-Modified: Mon, 06 Jul 2015 23:59:25 GMT
ETag: "d811d5844be3eaf9ab1f60dd36198aa9"
Vary: Accept
X-GitHub-Media-Type: github.v3; format=json
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: deny
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: ETag, Link, X-GitHub-OTP, X-RateLimit-Limit, X-RateLimit-Remaining, X-RateLimit-Reset, X-OAuth-Scopes, X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes, X-Poll-Interval
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
X-GitHub-Request-Id: 3EAD7342:6BF1:E180441:559F9D0D
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains; preload
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Served-By: bd82876e9bf04990f289ba22f246ee9b

{"login":"octocat","id":583231,"avatar_url":"https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/583231?v=3","gravatar_id":"","url":"https://api.github.com/users/octocat","html_url":"https://github.com/octocat","followers_url":"https://api.github.com/users/octocat/followers","following_url":"https://api.github.com/users/octocat/following{/other_user}","gists_url":"https://api.github.com/users/octocat/gists{/gist_id}","starred_url":"https://api.github.com/users/octocat/starred{/owner}{/repo}","subscriptions_url":"https://api.github.com/users/octocat/subscriptions","organizations_url":"https://api.github.com/users/octocat/orgs","repos_url":"https://api.github.com/users/octocat/repos","events_url":"https://api.github.com/users/octocat/events{/privacy}","received_events_url":"https://api.github.com/users/octocat/received_events","type":"User","site_admin":false,"name":"The Octocat","company":"GitHub","blog":"http://www.github.com/blog","location":"San Francisco","email":"octocat@github.com","hireable":false,"bio":null,"public_repos":5,"public_gists":8,"followers":1054,"following":6,"created_at":"2011-01-25T18:44:36Z","updated_at":"2015-07-06T23:59:25Z"}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following link answered my query. Now I know that the data sent in case of RESTful services is 'raw http' data.

http://rest.elkstein.org/2008/02/how-simple-is-rest.html